# Representing different types for dictionaries based on their keys

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I want to create a type that represents this dictionary

```py
{
   "13fc71ee-e676-4e5d-a561-a20af5bcbaaf": "123",
   "8d742ecf-6ae9-4408-a5a0-b1110f9b5365": "fdsafdsa",
   "literal": {
       "any": "dict",
   },
}
```

This is the closest type I can come up with:

```py
Dict[UUID | Literal["literal"], str | dict]
```

The main issue with the above type signature is that the following dictionary would be allowed:

```py
{
   "8d742ecf-6ae9-4408-a5a0-b1110f9b5365": {
       "dictionary": 321,
   },
   "literal": "some string",
}
```

Is there a way to annotate a dictionary with a type that can either be a UUID key for a string value *or* a string literal for a dict value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for potentially requires runtime knowledge and thus cannot be encoded (in a useful way) as a type. Perhaps there is a way to create a custom type that can work with static type checkers for some similar types, but I imagine it would be complicated. Thus, I propose some alternatives:

###### [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict):

```
class ItemType(TypedDict):
    uuids: dict[str, str]
    literal: dict[str, Any]

d: ItemType = {
    "uuids": {
        "13fc71ee-e676-4e5d-a561-a20af5bcbaaf": "123",
        "8d742ecf-6ae9-4408-a5a0-b1110f9b5365": "fdsafdsa",
    },
    "literal": {
        "any": "dict",
    },
}
```

###### Dataclasses:

```
@dataclass
class Item:
    uuids: dict[str, str]
    literal: dict[str, Any]

d = Item(**{
    "uuids": {
        "13fc71ee-e676-4e5d-a561-a20af5bcbaaf": "123",
        "8d742ecf-6ae9-4408-a5a0-b1110f9b5365": "fdsafdsa",
    },
    "literal": {
        "any": "dict",
    },
})
```

Optionally, one can consider overriding `__getitem__` to allow dictionary-like access `d["literal"]`.

###### Runtime checks

If all else fails, and you really need to verify constraints that the type system cannot handle, you can do various runtime checks via `isinstance` or perhaps via libraries like [`beartype`](https://github.com/beartype/beartype).